How to approximate the Koopman operator of a non-autonomous system?
For an autonomous system, the Koopman operator can be approximated by using dynamic mode decomposition (DMD).
I am looking for references that show how to approximate the Koopman operator $K$ (or its generator $L$) of time-dependent systems. In general, I would like to know whether it  is possible to have explicit represenatations of $K(t)$ and $L(t)$ as functions of time.

I don't think that explicit representations of the Koopman operator or its generator are known in general, even for autonomous systems. If they are, you can append the variables $\frac{dt}{ds}=1$ to the system and obtain an autonomous system and use that. If you have a periodic system in mind, maybe some sort of Floquet theory could be useful but I do not know of any general theory that could help you
